# CASTING to NUMERIC in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to understand the ARPU calculation in SQL from the following code, however I don't understand why the author has used NUMERIC with revenue in the 2nd query? Won't revenue (meal_price * order quantity) be numeric anyway?

[image]

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: I've seen people, who put casting everywhere just in case. But it is not needed here

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably the following.  `NUMERIC` is a specific data type.  However, it is not clear that `meal_price` and `order_quantity` are specifically `NUMERIC` -- and not some other type such as `INT`.

Many databases do integer division for `INT`, so `1 / 2` is 0 rather than 0.5.

The conversion to `NUMERIC` is a simple way to avoid integer division.

Answer (score 0):

Of course if a and b are numeric types , a * b will be numeric type

But there are many different numeric types, see

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-numeric.html

NUMERIC is a KEYWORK to specify numeric type of arbitrary précision, see previous link, it's often used to do exact calculations (accouinting) that cannoy be done in foating type.

In your case the author choosed to define the type he wants to use and not let the system/db choose for him. (try to figure out if a and b are integer what shoult be the type of the result 2 * 4 / 3 ?). It's a good practice.